# How to use @classmethod in python with inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, class-method

Code:

```
class parent:
    number = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.increment_number()
    @classmethod
    def increment_number(cls):
        cls.number += 1
class child1(main):
    def __init__(self):
        parent.__init__(self)
        self.current_number = self.number
class child2(main):
    def __init__(self):
        parent.__init__(self)
        self.current_number = self.number
a = child1()
print(a.current_number)
>>>1
b = child2()
print(b.current_number)
>>>1
c = child2()
print(c.current_number)
>>>2
```

I am trying to understand how to change a variable in a parent class. In this context the variable is `number`, so that `number` is also changed in all child classes.

At the moment it appears that the `increment_number` method changes the value of number for `child1` or `child2`.

The values of `current_number`, which represents the value of `number` when the object is created, that I desire are as follows:

```
a = child1()
print(a.current_number)
>>>1
b = child2()
print(b.current_number)
>>>2
c = child2()
print(c.current_number)
>>>3
```

Where every new object that inherits the parent class has an incremented value of `current_number`, no matter what class is being called.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `main` supposed to be `parent`?